# Visual studio code debugger issue

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am running

```
import json
items = json.loads('[{"id":1, "text": "Item 1"}, {"id":2, "text": "Item 2"}]')
for item in items:
    print(item['text'])
```

I am trying to debug the code. When the debugging finish I get the following error.

```
Unable to find the python module
Unable to find the python module
Unable to find the python module
```

I can run the code in the output and it give me the result.

Why I am I getting this error message? How can I fix this?

Comment: Your code does not explain the error message.

Comment: Your description is not clear but it could be that you have not defined a python interpreter for the debug environment?

Comment: Sorry, but could you provide a screenshot of it?